# JavaScript Object is set but is null when accessed

Tags: javascript, c#

I have the following object that constructs a session variable:

```
var sessionObject = function (key) {
    this._key = key;
    this._content;
    this.set = function (v) {
        this.setLocal(v);
        $.post('/Program/SetVariable',
        { key: this._key, value: v }, function (data) {
        });
    };
    this.get = function (callback) {
        var setterCallback = this.setLocal;
        $.get('/Program/GetVariable',
        { key: this._key }, function (data) {
            setterCallback(data);
        }).done(function () {
            callback();
        });
    };
    this.setLocal = function (v) {
        this._content = v;
    };
    this.getLocal = function () {
        return this._content;
    };
}
```

And my C# in the controller is as follows:

```
public ActionResult SetVariable(string key, string value)
{
    Session[key] = value;
    return this.Json(new { success = true });
}

public ActionResult GetVariable(string key)
{
    return this.Json(Session[key], JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I create a new session object every time the page is loaded, which references items in the session located on the server. When the session is set with the `set()` function, `_content` is set correctly and is **able** to be accessed publicly through `item.getLocal()` (either in the browser console or in code).

When I revisit the page and the session object referring to said item is already created, when I run the `item.get()` function it accesses the session variable and sets it to the `_content` object, I know this because I can do a `console.log(this._content)` in the `setLocal()` function which shows that the variable has been set correctly. But when I wish to access the content of the session object via either `this.getLocal()` or `item._content` while through the browser console or other lines of the code I get undefined returned to me.

So to illuminate the process some more this is what I do on a reload where there is already data in the session:

```
var item = new sessionObject("item");
item.get(printData);

function printData() {
   $("printbox").append(item.getLocal());
}
```

This does not print anything.

Is there a reason I can not access this item's content unless it is specifically set by the `item.set` function?

Comment: Are you creating instance of `sessionObject` ? And `this._content;` declaration is not required

Comment: Updated the question to show how I am using the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you do this:

```
var setterCallback = this.setLocal;
```

and call it like so:

```
setterCallback(data);
```

You have lost the context of your `sessionObject` instance, so the `this` inside the setLocal function is no longer your object instance but the global `window` object.

You can do two things to correct this, save a reference to `this` instead of saving a reference to the function and call setLocal from that reference

```
var that = this;
/.../
that.setLocal(data);
```

or you can [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) object instance when you save the setLocal reference

```
var setterCallack = this.setLocal.bind(this);
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you @Patrick, My confusion stemmed from the reference to `this` within the `$.get` request, which I thought I could get around by just using a variable as a reference. This has been an interesting learning experience.